# How to do a TRUNCATE query from JDO (Datanucleus)?

Tags: jdo, datanucleus

My requirement is to run a TRUNCATE query from Datanucleus, if possible.
So the below code:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery("javax.jdo.query.SQL", "TRUNCATE TABLE MYTABLE");
query.execute();
```

fails because the execute() method expects a result set which is missing in the case of TRUNCATE.

Up to now I tried several ways of doing it but none proved successful. (Also, I set the datanucleus.query.sql.allowAll=true)

Any hint would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Yea, faced a similar issue with `CREATE TABLE..`, couldn't find a solution either. Probably DN isn't designed for that !

Comment: I think the best thing to do would be to write a stored procedure containing "TRUNCATE" and this one should be called from DN (it supports calling stored procs).